# Delete rows by user ID using product hierarchy in CTE

Tags: sql-server, loops, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table with hundreds of thousands of user IDs and product codes. I use a CTE script within a WHILE loop to remove product IDs according to a hierarchy--i.e. if a user has products 18 and 19, I delete 19. If user has 17, 18, and 19, I delete 18 and 19. The problem is the loop is too costly and time consuming to work on the production tables.

The product IDs are not ordinal--they are simply IDs. My goal is to remove product ID rows according to the hierarchy shown in the code below--e.g. if 17 exists for user 1, remove products 18 and 19 if either or both exist. If product 18 and 19 exist such as for user 1, remove only 19 leaving product 18 alone.

In the following example, the lowest number in a group needs to be kept, but that is not always the case so I can't simply group product types and keep the MIN.

In the quick example below, user 1 should keep 18 and user 2 should keep 17. Instead, only user 2 is kept and both products are deleted for user 1. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    ID varchar(1),
    Prod varchar(2)
)
INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES ('1', '18')
      ,('1', '19')
      ,('2', '17')
      ,('2', '18')
      ,('2', '19')

--SELECT * FROM #tmp ORDER BY ID

;WITH CTE (ID, Prod)
        AS
        (SELECT ID, Prod FROM #tmp)
        DELETE FROM CTE
        WHERE (Prod = 19
            AND EXISTS (SELECT t.Prod
                        FROM #tmp t
                            INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ID = cte.ID 
                                AND t.Prod = CTE.Prod
                        WHERE t.Prod = 18
                        ))
        OR  (Prod = 18
            AND EXISTS (SELECT t.Prod
                        FROM #tmp t
                            INNER JOIN CTE ON  t.ID = cte.ID
                                AND t.Prod = CTE.Prod
                        WHERE t.Prod = 17   
                        ))
```

Comment: You need to explain your rules here. Simply saying that sometimes you keep the minimum but other times you don't makes no sense. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate your input. In my original, I say the following,

"i.e. if a user has products 18 and 19, I delete 19. If user has 17, 18, and 19, I delete 18 and 19. "

That is exactly what I want the sample code to do. I'm trying to use CTE to remove products for each user depending on what else they have attributed. The numbers are just ID numbers and not meant to be taken as ordinal.

Comment: In your example you have everything hardcoded. And you haven't explained **why** sometimes it will delete the lowest number but other times it doesn't.

Comment: I wish I knew. My intention was this: User 1 has product 19 and 18. In the DELETE statement, I wanted the code to say when the product = 19 is true, AND when the user ID in CTE matches #tmp and product 18 exists, delete the row containing 19.

What appears to be happening is the code is actually seeing that product 17 exists, even though it's for user 2 and not user 1, it's deleting products 18 and 19 for both users.

I can't figure out why it isn't limiting the delete to specific users. It's as though the join is operating like an outer join.

Comment: *but that is not always the case* - that's the only case you've described. You're missing a full description.

Comment: It doesn't matter what other cases exist in my production code--there are too many to list. The point here is that I need the results to be user 1, product 18 and user 2, product 17 in this very concise example. I point out that these IDs are not ordinal so an astute programmer would recognize that means I can't use ROW_NUMBER() or simply MIN() with user grouping.

The point is straightforward, I need CTE to accomplish a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "EXISTS" queries pretty much boil down to "are there any 18s in the table" and "are there any 17s in the table", which are both true, so all 19s and 18s will be deleted.

I think you want this

```
;WITH CTE (ID, Prod) AS (SELECT ID, Prod FROM #tmp)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE (Prod = 19 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp t WHERE Prod = 18 AND t.ID = CTE.ID))
OR  (Prod = 18 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp t WHERE Prod = 17 AND t.ID = CTE.ID))
```

Comment: I'll try this, but I think you've written what I already have. If you look at my code, there are parentheses that separate out the conditions just like what you've done. Like I said, I'll copy your sample and run it in my local to see if I've overlooked something. Either way, I appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Comment: The difference is that in your query you have additional copies of CTE inside the EXISTS, so the ID check will be on that copy. In my query it will correlate out to the main CTE table you are deleting from

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just couldn't see it. I had gone SQL blind from staring at it for too long. I ran your code, and it worked. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. It is much appreciated.